# Do cruise lines other than Royal and Carnival provide "active" activities?

Tags: cruising

My wife and I have been on plenty of cruises, but they have all been on Carnival and Royal. Carnival and Royal have giant slides, rock climbing walls, ice skating shows, surfing stations, silly contests, and things of that nature. Some areas have a luxury feel to them, but for the most part these cruises are very activity-centric

We like to go out and do things, especially during the days at sea. I kind of skim past other cruise lines because I am under the impression that they are more about relaxing and luxury than being fun. I am imagining them to be more about fine dining, gambling at the casino, and Broadway-style shows. They cater to couples and families without kids. That is what I am assuming, but I would like to confirm that with anyone who has been on any of these cruise lines.

Do lines like Celebrity and Norwegian have similar atmospheres to Royal and Carnival? Do they typically have things like rock climbing walls, basketball courts, games, events, and contests? Or are they, as I assume, more geared toward relaxing and luxury?

Comment: In general we don't do "update" or "edit" sections, we just change the content. The revision history is available for those who care. I've rearranged your text substantially and made it less opinion-seeking, but I don't believe I've put words in your mouth. Feel free to continue editing to ensure the question represents what you want to ask.

Comment: If you are looking for activities actually on the ships, then you have to look at each ship individually.  Newer ones have more amenities like game courts, climbing walls, etc.  Older ones do not (this applies to Carnival and RCCL as well).  If you are looking at shore activities, they all offer active things at certain ports of call and sedentary things at other ports.